# Forcing a broken line to stop with a timer

Tags: java, timer

I am querying a server (that I did not write) to get the HTML for a website, but the server has some bugs and sometimes does not return an answer. I have a catch in my method but it takes multiple minutes to kick in and in the mean time my code is stuck in limbo. The error happens at the  rd = new BufferedReader(new Input... line. Is there a way to use a timer to force my code out of the method if the server doesn't return an answer within a second or two? I end up with this bug only every couple hundred times the code runs.

```
public String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    BufferedReader rd;
    String line;
    String result = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urlToRead);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the existing timeout methods, [setConnectTimeout(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) and [setReadTimeout(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29).

If it times out, a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` is raised.

---

Unrelated, but consider not catching `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code in a different thread. After you start the thread you do `sleep` until a flag in the thread was set, or until x seconds passed. Then you go on with the main program.